# Sqlite JDBC in Java Server Page

Tags: java, sqlite, jsp

I am trying to use Sqlite on a web page over Java.
I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sqlite/JDBC
    model.DataBase.<init>(DataBase.java:35)
```

I've tried the two alternatives:

```
    this.conn = new org.sqlite.JDBC().connect("jdbc:sqlite:" + file, new Properties());
    this.stm = this.conn.createStatement();
```

and

```
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + file);
    this.stm = this.conn.createStatement();
```

I am using Eclipse and I've configured the jar file in the build path, also, when running as a desktop application it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just having the sqllite.jar in your build path is not enough. If you are running it as a web application place the jar in the /WEB-INF/lib folder as well.

You can tell eclipse to export that file as well.

Comment: No need to fiddle with build path / export properties. Just dropping JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said that you've included the jar file in your build path, but if it's not also in the `$CLASSPATH` of the server you're running under, then you'll end up with this exception.  If the Java Classloader can't find the class inside a jar file that it knows about, you'll get `NoClassDefFoundError`.  I suggest checking the classpath.